# Why does my Localizable WinForm only show the English view?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I have a WinForm where I have enabled Localizable. I changed the Language to `en-US` and saved. Then I changed the Language to `es-MX` changed all my Labels, Column Headers, and Button text to Spanish and saved that. I can now switch back and forth between the two Forms.

I ran the program and the English view came up just fine. I edited the code-behind of that form and put the following line in at the end of the form constructor:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
```

I ran the program again and still the English view came up. I have a Debug statement in my `OnLoad` method that writes the current culture and it shows `es-MX`. What step have I missed?

Comment: "At the end" is too late, it has to appear before the InitializeComponent() call.  Better yet, in your Main() method.  And you have to set the CurrentUICulture as well.  And just don't since it will already be set correctly on the machine of a Mexican user.

Comment: I move setting the culture to the top of the constructor. I could not get it to work from the OnLoad method. I am just testing now, I understand the user's workstation's settings should be what the language settings are base on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change UI culture you have to set:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
```

I think this should correct your issue.

For more information, read [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN.